# TensorFlow's target pruning can't find nodes

Tags: tensorflow

I wrote a Python script using the TensorFlow API, including a `SummaryWriter` that dumps the graph definition so I can look at it in TensorBoard.

When running the script, a `NotFoundError` is thrown saying `PruneForTargets: Some target nodes not found: Reading/data_queue_EnqueueMany_1`. As its name implies, the node in question was created by an `enqueue_many` call on a `FIFOQueue` (which is then started in a `QueueRunner`); it does in fact exist, and can be seen clearly in TensorBoard.

What could cause TensorFlow to not find some nodes?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a known issue that occurs when you start threads that access the TensorFlow graph (e.g. your `QueueRunner`) before adding more nodes to the graph. (The underlying `tf.Graph` data structure is not thread-safe for concurrent reads and writes.)

The solution is to move [`tf.train.start_queue_runners(sess)`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.8/api_docs/python/train.html#start_queue_runners) (and any other code that starts threads) *after* the last node is constructed. One way to double-check this is to add a call to [`tf.get_default_graph().finalize()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.8/api_docs/python/framework.html#Graph.finalize) immediately before calling `start_queue_runners()`.